# What do the markdown vendor files do for mailables?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, markdown

I'm using laravel with markdown emails.

```
return $this->from('test@test.com', 'test')
   ->subject($this->subject)
   ->markdown('emails.test');
```

I published the vendor files into my repository by running:

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail`

That gave me the `views/vendor/mail/html` folder and the `views/vendor/mail/markdown` folder.

I'm not sure what the files in the markdown folder are doing. Most of these files only contain a little bit of code. i.e.

`markdown/header.php`

```
{{ $slot }}
```

When I delete `{{ $slot }}` my emails don't render any differently. I can delete any content in any of these files and nothing changes. I do however have to make sure these files exist.

I want to use these files to put markdown content that's static across all my emails. Currently the only way I can achieve this is to put that content in the `views/vendor/mail/html` directory.

How can I have static content written in markdown in my mailables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two folder works together and is intended for ease of use if you want to configure the views for your emails.

Before laravel 5.8 it was called `HTML` and `markdown`, and in 5.8 and later it is `HTML` and `text`.

Every file in the markdown(or text if youre in 5.8 or above), corresponds with a file in the html folder, and is parsed there. 
For example, this is the `subcopy`(the body of the mail) file in the `html` folder:

```
<table class="subcopy" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse($slot) }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It's parsing the `subcopy.blade.php` in the markdown folder.

Comment: Ok thanks, So how come when I delete all the content in `mail/text/message.blade.php` or `mail/text/layout.blade.php` nothing changes in my mailable? I would expect it to not render or to throw an error.

Comment: Are you sending the mail as a notification or as `mailable`?

Comment: As a mailable. `Mail::to('test@test')->send(new TestMailable());`  OOohh, So the text folder is only for the text version of the email?  Ok I thought they were interacting some how.

Comment: Ok, you got me down the right path. As I said in my previous comment. The text folder is only for the text version of the email and has nothing to do with the rendering.